# class __init__ takes parameters but turns them into tuples for some reason

Tags: python, class

I have a very simple class:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, guid, sku, name):
        self.guid = guid,
        self.sku = sku,
        self.name = name
```

When I create an object, such as:

```
item1 = Item('abc123', 1, 'abc1')
```

And I do:

```
print item1.guid
```

I get this as an output:

```
('abc123',)
```

Instead of the expected:

```
'abc123'
```

Any idea why it does this?

P.S.: `name` works as expected!

Comment: What are those commas doing? You are defining tuples. Remove them! `self.guid = guid`

Comment: It is because you have comma in them

Comment: "PS: `name` works as expected" When you see things like this, you should be thinking, "What is different about this one?" This might have led you to the right answer in this case, since it's the only one not followed by a comma.

Answer (score 19):

```
    self.guid = guid,   # Comma means create a tuple!
    self.sku = sku,
    self.name = name
```

You have done this yourself in your `__init__` code. The tuple is constructed by a comma. Parentheses are just there to avoid ambiguity in some cases.

The correct code looks like this:

```
    self.guid = guid
    self.sku = sku
    self.name = name
```

Comment: What a silly mistake! Thanks (will pop your answer as 'Answer' in 9 mins when it allows me to).

Comment: I have spent a day trying to figure this out, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Python isn't doing it, you are, right here:

```
self.guid = guid,
self.sku = sku,
```

Notice those trailing commas? In python, the `,` is actually what constructs tuples. So `guid,` is saying "make a tuple of size one with guid as the element". Remove the trailing commas and you're good to go.

Unfortunately the `,` operator is also the argument separator in function calls and inline initialization of lists/dicts, so typically you encounter "tuple construction" as `(a,b)`. But the `()` are only there to let the interpreter disambiguate between the `,` tuple construction operator and the `,` argument delimiter. If you're not in a case where there is such ambiguity, like an assignment, the `,` operator is all you need, even if nothing comes after it.